# Permission audit on Windows file system

Tags: windows, security, permissions, filesystems

We're connecting a SharePoint 2010 to our file system so it can crawl and index the files on our network. However, the files have incorrect permissions in many cases and so we need to perform a comprehensive file security audit to determine what accounts have which level of access to files/folders.

Are there free tools to accomplish this network file system security audit and provide detailed information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I audit file server permissions [Helge Klein's wonderful SetACL utility](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/) in its "list" mode to generate a list of non-inherited permissions (using either the `cont_obj` or `cont` recursion options, depending on whether I want to see files and folders or just files). Then I typically use simple tools like `grep` to filter out "noise" that I don't want to see from the resulting output.

Answer (score 2):

There are some free tools that will do this, I had to do the same thing yesterday (incidentally also for a Sharepoint related issue) and a quick Google search revealed a number of options. Personally I don't have any experience with any of them or the developers that make them so I'm not going to make any recommendations here.

What I ended up doing was using Powershell to audit the permissions. You don't mention which version of Windows you're using so I don't know whether you have it installed automatically or not (if not you can download and install it). But I found a script [here](http://jfrmilner.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/audit-ntfs-permissions-powershell-script/) for auditing permissions across multiple servers, which I adapted for use on just one.

If you want to write your own script to accomplish this (Powershell is easy, it doesn't take much to write very basic scripts), you can read up on the Get-ACL cmdlet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347635.aspx)
.